# uiview is corrupted when the view rotate during screen transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, landscape-portrait

I am developing application which can be used on Landscape and Portrait.
I have a problem.

UIView sometimes corrupt when the view rotate during screen transition.
I attached capture.

[image]

Same screen(capture screen) rotation again,Screen is not going to corrupt.

What is this problem?

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: Yes,I use auto -layout.

Comment: I suggest to check again the rules of your controls... try to reset the rules ank re-make it